# Why is SCNNode.rotation property a four dimensional vector?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I don't understand why [SCNNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNNode)'s rotation property is a SCNVector4 instead of a SCNVector3. The documentation states that:

> The four-component rotation vector specifies the direction of the rotation axis in the first three components **and the angle of rotation (in radians) in the fourth**. The default rotation is the zero vector, specifying no rotation. Rotation is applied relative to the node’s pivot property.

What's the fourth axis? I tried adding a light ([SCNLight](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNLight_Class/index.html)) and if I don't specify the value of the 4th float in the vector the light has no effect (the scene is dark). Why? shouldn't a 3-dimensional vector (x,y,z) be enough?

Comment: I'm confused, you seem to ask about 2 un-related topics. How to you set-up the light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation specifies, the first 3 values will specify the 3d position of the axis for rotating the light, while the 4th parameter will specify the rotation around that axis.

For instance, specifying (pseudo-code) `(0, 0, 1, degToRad(45))` will have the effect of a light that will be rotated 45 degrees around the vertical axis (assuming that z is up), coming from the pivot location.

Now the fact that if you don't specify a value for the w (the 4th parameter), it does not light the scene, it might be related to the fact that your light is a directional light, or a spot, and the default 0 value lights in the opposite direction of where the scene is.

Comment: Side-note: In SceneKit, Y is up and Z is forward.